# How to print .docx,doc,xls,csv in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I print .docx,doc,xls,csv in rails 4?

I tried window.open and window.print using javascript, but each time when it invokes window.open it downloads the file.

I tried to embed that in an iframe, that also fails.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a specific type of file isn't something that relies on your application it relies on the browser. In common browsers there is no support to display the file formats you mentioned.

What you can do is implementing some document viewers based on js if they are available for your usage. For example I know there is a plugin viewer.js that provides functionality to convert office and pdf to html. That might help you out... https://developers.box.com/viewer-js-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel) some time back and this is the blog which i refereed. Helped a great deal.

Hope this helps.